# Exponential, supermartinagles

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have a question about super-martingale and martingale convergence theorem.

Fix $T>0,\lambda>0$. For a continuous local martingale $X=(X)_{t \in [0,T]}$, we can define

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{E}^{\lambda}(X)_{t}=\exp \left\{ \lambda X_{t}-\frac{\lambda^{2}}{2} \langle X,X\rangle_{t}  \right\}
\end{align*}

By Itô's formula, $\mathcal{E}^{\lambda}(X)$ is a local martingale. Since $\mathcal{E}^{\lambda}(X)$ is positive, futhermore, we can show that $\mathcal{E}^{\lambda}(X)$ is **super-martingale.**

**My question**

When $X_{0}=0$, can we show that $\displaystyle \mathcal{E}^{\lambda}(X)_{t} \underset{t \to0}\longrightarrow 1$ in $L^{1}(\Omega)$ ?

**My attempt**

It is clear that  $\lim_{t \to 0}\mathcal{E}^{\lambda}(X)_{t}= 1$ $P$-a.s. . If 
$\mathcal{E}^{\lambda}(X)$ is **martinagle**, $(\mathcal{E}^{\lambda}(X)_{t})_{t \in [0,T]}$ is uniformly integrable. Therefore we can get  $\displaystyle \mathcal{E}^{\lambda}(X)_{t} \underset{t \to0}\longrightarrow 1$ in $L^{1}(\Omega)$.

Can we show that $\displaystyle \mathcal{E}^{\lambda}(X)_{t} \underset{t \to0}\longrightarrow 1$ in $L^{1}(\Omega)$ if $\mathcal{E}^{\lambda}(X)$ is **super-martingale** ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Correction: $\mathcal E^\lambda(X)$ is a local martingale provided $X$ is a continuous *local martingale*.

Comment: HInt: Backward martingale convergence theorem.  ($\mathcal E^\lambda(X)$ is, as you observe, a positive supermartingale.)